# Checking if dice roll is between a range of numbers

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and am working on a text RPG. I've been able to get it able to tell me whether or not I have a random encounter, but not what I come across. I am trying to add an encounter table with 2d6 and am having trouble understanding `if` statements and how to check between a range of numbers.

```
import random

Encounter =  5

d20 = random.randint(1,20)
print("your d20 rolled a" , d20)

d6 = random.randint(1,6)
#print("your d6 rolled a" , d6)

d6x2 = d6 + random.randint(1,6)
print("you rolled a", d6x2, "on two d6")

if Encounter >= 5:
    if d20 >= 10:
        print("You have an encounter!")
        if d6x2 == (2,5):
            print("A guard catches you trying to escape!")
        elif d6x2 == (6,8):
            print("Thank goodness, it's just a rat.")
        elif d6x2 == (9,12):
            print("Oh great, another prisoner. I wonder if he wants to join you...")
    elif d20 < 10:
        print("You got lucky and don't have an encounter")
else:
    print("You don't have an encounter")
```

Even though `d6x2` is returning values in the ranges stated the encounter text isn't printing. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and have had a really had time trying to word my question while looking elsewhere on the internet so I'm sorry if this doesn't make much sense. Why won't the `if` and `elif` text print?

I have tried changing `if d6x2 == (2,5):` to `if d6x2 == range(2,5)` but I'm sure I'm using that function wrong.

Comment: FYI: You asked about `if` statements, but neither your confusion, nor the answer that you accepted has anything to do with `if` statements. It's really a question about [_truthiness_](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/truthiness/). `d6x2==(2,5)` is an [_expression_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)—its a piece of code that Python can _evaluate_ to produce a _value._ Likewise, `2<=d6x2<=5` and `d6x2 in range(2,6)` are expressions that produce values. An `if` statement is just one of many places in Python where an expression is evaluated to produce a value, and it is one of...

Comment: ...several places in Python where it's the truthiness of some value that determines an outcome. The answer to your question depends on what _kind_ of value\* is produced by each of those different expressions and, on how the truthiness of those values is tested. \[\* Actually, they all yield _boolean_ values, whose truthiness is trivially tested, but in principle, you can test the truthiness of _any_ value `v` by using an `if v:...` statement.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d6x2` is a single integer and it can never be equal to a tuple (`(2, 5)`) or a range (`range(2, 5)`). You should either use mathematical inequalities:

```
if 2 <= d6x2 <= 5:
```

or the `in` operator with `range`:

```
if d6x2 in range(2, 6):
```